# Continuous mapping $D^2 \to S^1$

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology

It is a well known result in algebraic topology that there is no retraction of $D^2$ onto $S^1$.

Does anyone know any continuous maps $D^2 \to S^1$ which are not constant?

Comment: $e^{i\pi|z|}{}$

Comment: There are no continuous maps of $D^2$ to $S^1$ that are the identity on $S^1\subset D^2$.

Comment: In particular, a map $f:S^1\rightarrow S^1$ can be extended to all of $D^2$ if and only if $f$ is homotopy-equivalent to a constant.

Comment: I have to ask: how does one get to the point where one knows what a retraction is and, well, that algebraic topology is something, and is not able to construct a non-const. cont. function like that? :/

Comment: Since Mariano's comment was up voted so many times I feel compelled to respond! I was trying to come up with a map from D^2 to S^1 which when restricted to the boundary has degree 2. I couldn't think of one which is why I asked the question. I probably should have been more explicit. Thomas answered this question though...

Comment: @Dbr: Your map would be a map $S^1\to S^1$ which factors through $D^2$. Since $D^2$ is contractible, your original map is null, hence degree 0.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about the map that sends $$(x,y)\in D^2=\{(x,y)\in\mathbb{R}^2\mid x^2+y^2\leq 1\}$$ to $$(\textstyle\sqrt{1-y^2},y)\in S^1=\{(x,y)\in\mathbb{R}^2\mid x^2+y^2=1\}$$

Answer (score 3):

If you can think of a path $\gamma\colon I \to S^1$, then you get a continuous map $D^2 \to S^1$ by first collapsing $D^2$ to the interval $I$ and then composing with your path.

If your path $\gamma$ was not constant, then the resulting map $D^2 \to S^1$ will not be constant.